# c++ overload operator= for a string

Tags: c++

```
Word Word::operator= (const Word& RHS) const{

    if(word != RHS.GetWord()){
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss here, how do you effectively delete the current object string, then copy the inputed string to it?

Comment: If `wordText` is a `std::string`, there is no need to override the implicit definition at all. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I think you are looking for `swap()`.

Comment: Yes wordText is a string. C++ is preventing me from simply saying wordText = RHS.GetWord().

Comment: And what is the return type of `GetWord`?  Could you extend your code to show a minimal but complete `Word` class?  Also note that the assignment operator should return a *reference* to the assigned-to object, not a copy.

Comment: Regarding your update: If that three are all members, the compiler-generated assignment operator is just fine.  Don't type anything.  (But the example is still incomplete.  You didn't show the *declaration* of the `Word` class.)

Answer (score 3):

Your error is on the prototype:

```
Word  Word::operator= (const Word& RHS) const{
//  ^                                   ^^^^^ ???
```

An assignment-operator is useless on a constant object, so the last `const` is bad.
Also, a flaw the compiler cannot diagnose (unless you use it somewhere an lvalue is neccessary), it should return by reference.

Anyway, as a member-by-member-copy is good enough, there is no sense in defining your own assignment-operator at all:
Use the default one.